# Unable to connect to wifi from new Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, wireless

I regularly use Ubuntu for work but never had this problem before. On my personal computer HP ENVY I decided to have Ubuntu 16.04 alongside windows 8. Installation went fine. When I logged in, I could not see option for wifi connection. I looked up few forums but none of them helped. So far I have tried the following :

1. Installed fresh copy of Ubuntu
2. installed Linux-mint just to see if it works.
3. Settings > Software & Updates > Additional Drivers > Update
4. install firmware-b43-installer

None of it worked. Is there any solution to it? I am fed up of not understanding what is wrong.

After running the command

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
```

I get following output:

```
Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n
[14e4:4365] (rev 01)    DeviceName: Broadcom BCM43142 802.11bgn 1x1 WiFi
Adapter + BT 4.0 combo adapter  Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company
BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [103c:2230]
```

Currently I am using Ethernet connection.

command

```
sudo lshw -C network
```

gives following output

```
 *-network UNCLAIMED     
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM43142 802.11b/g/n
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:b2500000-b2507fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: eno1
       version: 10
       serial: 3c:a8:2a:b4:74:51
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8168g-3_0.0.1 04/23/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:28 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:b2404000-b2404fff memory:b2400000-b2403fff
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the Broadcom wireless drivers for your machine. One needs to install a different package for different PCI-ID's. Fortunately, an answer has already been provided for a question regarding installation of Broadcom Wireless Drivers. Follow the link of the question provided below

[Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

Answer (score 0):

If rebooting doesn't fix your issue, run

```
lspci | grep Wireless
```

and search for the drivers for your adapter, then install them. If they require you to build them from the source, then run

```
make
sudo make install
reboot
```

and it should work.

Comment: As stated in question description, I already tried that, it is not working.

Comment: > lspci | grep Wireless 

Doesn't give any output

Comment: Are you sure you are typing capital "w", lscpi  | grep ***W***ireless

Comment: Try with a lowercase 'w', but it appears your adapter is a BCM43142.